# Append array to div

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a following script it return only "h" letter to appended div#main. But i want append all this array element to main. And how can i create breakline when it print every letter?

```
<div id="main"></div>

<script>
    function for_array(divname, myarray) {
        for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
            text = document.createTextNode(myarray[i]);
        }
        return document.getElementById(divname).appendChild(text);
    }
    for_array("main", ['f', 't', 'tr', 'h']);
</script>
```

Comment: Try `text = document.createTextNode(myarray[i] + '<br>');`

Comment: this would insert <br> as a text element, w/o being interpreted as html :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the content within the for loop, like this

```
for (let i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
   const text = document.createTextNode(myarray[i]);
   const lineBreak = document.createElement('br');
   document.getElementById(divname).appendChild(text)
   document.getElementById(divname).appendChild(lineBreak);
}
```

In the case you've shown only the last element is appended, because the for-loop is simply iterating, without appending. Only when it is done the last character is being appended.
Note also that here a `<br />` element is being created and appended after the character in order to insert a line break.

---

Here is a full working example

```js
function for_array(divname, myarray) {
  for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
    const text = document.createTextNode(myarray[i]);
    const lineBreak = document.createElement('br');
    document.getElementById(divname).appendChild(text)
    document.getElementById(divname).appendChild(lineBreak);
  }
}

for_array("main", ['f', 't', 'tr', 'h']);
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: I am newbie in javascript. What is mean "let" words to do? How can I add breakline in every array element?

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to create new elements all the time, when assigning a string to *innerHTML*, it gets parsed automatically:

```
document.getElementById(divname).innerHTML=myarray.join("<br>");
```

This is whats happening:

```
['f', 't', 'tr', 'h'] 
/* join with <br> => */
 'f<br>t<br>tr<br>h' 
//assigned to DOM, <br> gets parsed to a line break:
f
br
tr
h
```

Comment: thanks but read about innerHTML is slow than appendchild. https://gist.github.com/oliverfernandez/5619180 see this link

Comment: @ОтгонбаярЛамжав im not using innerHTML in a loop... using .join is faster then iterating over the array, which should make the whole thing much much faster

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way.

```
$(function(){
    function for_array(divname, myarray) {
       $.each(myarray, function(index, val) {
        $('#main').append(val+"<br/>");
       });
    }
    for_array("main", ['f', 't', 'tr', 'h']);
    })
```

Comment: you may not answer with jquery on a pure js question